# CTRL + / uncomments first line in sublime text file

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

In SublimeText 3, I have a javascript file with its few first line with comments like

```
/* this js file is mine *
** more info **
end of comments */
```

While editing, if hitting the `ctrl + /` shortcut at certain cursor positions - the current line won't be commented, but the first line of the file would get uncommented. - effectively destroying the file..

If i hit the key again without moving the cursor, the current line get commented as expected, and toggles if I try once more.

EXAMPLE: with this line `if (viewport.width >= 768) {` if the cursor is at the end of the line - this will happen,
but if the cursor is in the word `width` it will toggle as expected.

Happens on various files / projects.
Couln't find any reference to it here or on github.

Comment: this sounds like it's specific to your editor, not javascript

Comment: True. it is a SublimeText issue of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

as per SublimeText Forum issue `https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=19402&p=74203`

It's kind of a hack:

- Deleting [better- renaming] the Packages folder from SublimeText3 configuration directory and then running ST3 again will cause it to install its necessary packages.
- Then, manually install all of your old packages [you can copy the config files from the renamed directory]

Issue should be resolved.